# Higher Order Function (uncurry,curry)

Tags: haskell

I'm using these functions:

```
cplus a b = a+b   

ucplus(a, b) = a+b
```

...to do this experiment:

```
uncurry cplus=\(a, b) -> cplus a b
```

`(a,b)` is the parameter of the function `cplus`, so the right side of equation is actually doing the function `cplus a b`.

Why does `uncurry cplus` equal the right side of the equation?

Comment: "So why uncurry cplus equal to the right side of the equation?" - This broken English was very difficult to decipher; the code was also confusing. Can someone please clarify the presentation of this question?

Answer (score 6):

`uncurry` is defined as follows:

```
uncurry f = \(a,b) -> f a b
```

When you apply the function `uncurry` to the function `f`, it returns a function like `f`, but instead of a 'curried' function, you get a function which takes a tuple.

The type signature of `uncurry` is `(a -> (b -> c)) -> ((a, b) -> c)`. That is, it takes a function of type `a -> (b -> c)` and returns a function of type `(a, b) -> c`.

`cplus` is a *curried function* -- that means, it is a function that returns another function. The curried form of `cplus` could be written:

```
cplus = (\a -> (\b -> a + b))
```

But in most functional languages, the syntax `cplus a b = a+b` is equivalent.

Comment: Why the type signature of uncurry is (a -> (b -> c)) -> ((a, b) ->c). On the left side of ‘->’ (a -> (b -> c))。I think you just use the specific example of uncurry cplus to explain its type signature.On the left side is just type signature of cplus,and the right side is uncurry.

Comment: uncurry is a function which takes a function as its argument, and returns another function. The input function is a function which takes 'a' as its argument, and returns a function 'b -> c'. The output function is a function which takes '(a,b)' as its argument and returns 'c'.